# Google sheets API - Python - Return value of cell without brackets

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I am trying to read from a cell in one of the sheets I have uploaded to append the values in a presentation.
However, when I use the code

```
valueCount = SHEETS.spreadsheets().values().get(range='C7',
        spreadsheetId=ssID).execute().get('values')
```

the value returned is wrapped in double brackets and single quotes, like if cell C7 had a value of 350, the response of that call above will output as [['350']]

I only want to get 350. Is there a way to do it from within the API? Or some way to clean up the string in Python? I'd honestly prefer if I could have it returned cleansed from the start.

The weird part is that when replicating the example on [How to create and fill tables in google slides](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/11/generating-slides-from-spreadsheet-data.html), it actually does return just the number with no problem, but it's exactly the same call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the method of spreadsheets.values.get in Sheets API, the values are returned as 2 dimensional array. This is the specification. And also, the default value of `valueRenderOption` is `FORMATTED_VALUE`. I think that the reason of `[["350"]]` is due to them.

In your case, you retrieves the value from one cell. In this case, the value is always `[[###]]`. So in order to retrieve `350` from `C7` in the 1st tab of the Google Spreadsheet, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
valueCount = SHEETS.spreadsheets().values().get(range='C7',spreadsheetId=ssID, valueRenderOption='UNFORMATTED_VALUE').execute().get('values')
res = valueCount[0][0]
```

- In this case, `valueRenderOption='UNFORMATTED_VALUE'` is used.
- `valueCount` is `[[350]]`.
- By this, `res` is `350` and the type is `int`.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [ValueRenderOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption)